# What's my mistake with this chain of nullspaces computation,

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

Say I have a 5x5 matrix A and I know it is nilpotent, with nilpotence degree = 3.

I compute its null-spaces for $A$, $A^2$,and $A^3$, call each null-space K1, K2, K3, respectively.

I find that K1 (i.e., the eigenspace of A), is of dimension =2.  So, I have two independent eigenvectors that span K1.

Similarly, for K2, I find it is of dimension 3, so that dim(K2\K1) = 1.

Finally, dim(K3) = 5, so that dim(K3 \ K2) = 2.

Here is my confusion:  I have two linearly independent vectors that span the space K3\K2.  With these two vectors in the "top layer", I can then carve out two cyclic subspaces of dimension 3, since each vector gets killed only when I apply A to it three times.

But this gives me a factorization of V into two cyclic subspaces, with total dimension = ... 6?  But dim(V) =5.

What have I assumed incorrectly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d_k$ is the nullity of $A^k$ then the sequence
$$d_0=0,\,d_1,\,d_2,\,d_3,\,\ldots$$
has two important properties:

- $d_0\le d_1\le d_2\le d_3\le\cdots\,$;
- $d_1-d_0\ge d_2-d_1\ge d_3-d_2\ge\cdots\,$.

That is, the nullities must be (non-strictly) increasing, and the successive differences must be (non-strictly) decreasing.

Your nullity sequence $0,2,3,5$ violates the second of these and hence is not possible.

**Sketch of proof** for the second property.  Take a basis for $\ker(A^k)$, extend to a basis for $\ker(A^{k+1})$ and then to $\ker(A^{k+2})$, so we get say
$$\def\u{{\bf u}}\def\v{{\bf v}}\def\w{{\bf w}}
\{\u_1,\ldots,\u_p,\v_1,\ldots,\v_q,\w_1\ldots,\w_r\}\ .$$
We need to prove that $r\le q$.  To do this consider the vectors $\w_1,\ldots,\w_r$ and write
$$\def\x{{\bf x}}\def\y{{\bf y}}
  A\w_j=\x_j+\y_j\quad\hbox{with}\quad \x_j\in span\{\u_1,\ldots,\u_p\},\ 
  \y_j\in span\{\v_1,\ldots,\v_q\}\ .$$
Then you can show that the $\y_j$ are linearly independent, so we have $r$ independent vectors in a space spanned by $q$ vectors, so $r\le q$ as required.

Comment: Hi @David, I am aware of the first property because of the inclusions in this direction: K3 $\supset$ K2 $\supset$ K1 $\supset$ K0 = {0}, but I was not aware of the second property - that the successive differences in dimension must be (non-strictly) decreasing.  The problems on nilpotent matrices, Jordan form computations have all been sort of easy, so I just made up this example to be different from what I've already computed successfully, and I sketched the nullspaces for this idea and noticed that something wasn't right.

Comment: I had thought all that was required was the first property you stated...

Comment: Thanks for your time.  I will read up on the second property.  Have a great night @David :-)

Comment: OK, I understand - I thought you were dealing with a specific matrix $A$.  I have added a brief proof of the second property.  Actually I'll aim to have a great day where I am ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much @David!  Ohhh...right...I hope you had a nice, big breakfast and have a great day! :-)